# Why should one not share his or her totem?

Tags: plot-explanation, inception

In the movie *Inception*, why didn't Arthur allow Ariadne to see his totem, which was a loaded die?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He allowed her to *see it*, but not *touch it*. The whole point of a totem is that it should act in such a way as to only be recognisable by the owner (preferably by feel).

**The special weighting on his loaded dice is only known to him. When he picks it up, that instantly tells him that he's within reality, or at least within a dream of his own making.**

> **ARTHUR:** *I can’t let you handle it. That’s the point. No one else can know the weight or balance of it.*
>
> **ARIADNE:** *Why?*
>
> **ARTHUR:** *So when you examine your totem... You know, beyond a doubt, that you’re not in someone else’s dream.*

This is also seen when Saito realises that he's inside a dream when he lands on the *polyester* rug.

> ... he NOTICES SOMETHING. And starts LAUGHING.
>
> **SAITO:** *I've always hated this carpet. It's stained and frayed in such distinctive ways... But very definitely made of wool. Right now
>   I'm lying on polyester.*